# ASP.NET MVC3 Partial View on HTTPPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I Have a View and Partial View. The layout for the view is something like this:

```
<html>
...
<div id="MainView">@RenderBody()</div>

<!--Partial View-->
<div id="partialView">@Html.Action("PartialViewForm", "Main")</div>
...
</html>
```

My Partial View (named as _Register) is something like this:

```
@model PartialViewModel    
<div id="form">
@using (Html.BeginForm("PartialViewForm", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table  >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)*</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</td>
                <td align="left">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "")</td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Go" class="submit2"/></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
</div>
```

In my MainController I have methods like this:

```
public class MainController  : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PartialViewForm()
    {
        var partialViewModel= new PartialViewModel();   
        return PartialView("_Register", partialViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartialViewForm(PartialViewModel partialViewModel )
    {
        // if Validation is not successfull 
        return PartialView("_Register", partialViewModel);

       //  else
       ....
    }
 }
```

This is what I want to do... when validation fails on the partial view I want to g back to the main view... however in my case on the post action when validation fails all I can see is the partialview... there is no main page content. 
There are posts on the forum that show the same kind of behavior but I am not able to solve my issue. Can anyone please tell me how to fix it (it will be really helpful if you can modify my example and show it)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand what you are trying to do but if what I'm thinking is right, you should just use

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialViewForm(PartialViewModel partialViewModel )
{
    // if Validation is not successfull
    model = _db.getBlah(); //get the original model for the main view
    return View("MainView", model);

   //  else
   ....
}
```

However I think your issue might be that you really should have your form submission in your main view and not in your partial - the partial is just there to render the editors for your Create/Edit views, etc; the data should be submitted to the main view's action so that it can create/update the proper model.